# Configure Eclipse to build & run different applications

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've got my project separated into folders. Two of this folders are `src` and `tests`.

- `src` contains `main.cpp` and its own `makefile`
- `tests` contains `tests.cpp` and its own `makefile`

Up until now, I only compiled and ran `tests.cpp`, but now I need to be able to compile `main.cpp` and run it, as a separate program. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Please refer [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_new_run_config.htm) to create, manage and run configuration for C++ programs.
2. To manage the property of the program refer [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_builders.htm)
3. To make target refer [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_create_make_target.htm).

You can define configuration in your eclipse and run them separately.

Go to `Run`-> `Run Configuration` and declare your own configuration depending on nature of the applicaiton. The image below specified how to create a new configuration for Java program. You can do the same for c++ program as well.

Once you have that dialog box. You need to do right click to create a new configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding a target for each file that you want to compile and then add them to the build settings of your project.
Have a look at the following link about using makefiles in Eclipse:

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_create_make_target.htm